# Changed +load method order in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xcode7, objective-c-runtime

I found out that Xcode 7 (Version 7.0 (7A220)) changed the order in which `+load` methods for classes and categories are called during unit tests.

If a category belonging to the test target implements a `+load` method, it is now called at the end, when instances of the class might've already been created and used.

I have an `AppDelegate`, which implements `+load` method. The `AppDelegate.m` file also contains `AppDelegate (MainModule)` category. Additionally, there is a unit test file `LoadMethodTestTests.m`, which contains another category – `AppDelegate (UnitTest)`.

Both categories also implement `+load` method. The first category belongs to the main target, the second one – to the test target.

## Code

I made a small [test project](https://github.com/DMAPro/LoadMethodTest) to demonstrate the issue.
It is an empty default Xcode one view project with only two files changed.

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

+(void)load {
    NSLog(@"Class load");
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");

    return YES;
}

@end

@interface AppDelegate (MainModule)
@end

@implementation AppDelegate (MainModule)

+(void)load {
    NSLog(@"Main Module +load");
}

@end
```

And a unit test file (LoadMethodTestTests.m):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface LoadMethodTestTests : XCTestCase

@end

@interface AppDelegate (UnitTest)
@end

@implementation AppDelegate (UnitTest)

+(void)load {
    NSLog(@"Unit Test +load");
}

@end

@implementation LoadMethodTestTests

-(void)testEmptyTest {
    XCTAssert(YES);
}

@end
```

## Testing

I performed Unit Testing of this project (the code and the github link are below) on Xcode 6/7 and got the following `+load` calls order:

```
Xcode 6 (iOS 8.4 simulator):
    Unit Test +load
    Class load
    Main Module +load
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Xcode 7 (iOS 9 simulator):
    Class load
    Main Module +load
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    Unit Test +load

Xcode 7 (iOS 8.4 simulator):
    Class load
    Main Module +load
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    Unit Test +load
```

## Question

Xcode 7 runs the test target category `+load` method (`Unit Test +load`) in the end, after the `AppDelegate` has already been created.
**Is it a correct behavior or is it a bug that should be sent to Apple?**

May be it is not specified, so the compiler/runtime is free to rearrange calls?
I had a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326435/nsobject-load-and-initialize-what-do-they-do) as well as on the [+load description in the NSObject documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load) but I didn't quite understand how the `+load` method is supposed to work when the category belongs to another target.

Or may be `AppDelegate` is some sort of a special case for some reason?

## Why I'm asking this

1. Educational purposes.
2. I used to perform method swizzling in a category inside unit test target. Now, when the call order has changed, `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is performed before the swizzling takes place. There are other ways to do it, I believe, but it just seems counter-intuitive to me the way it works in Xcode 7. I thought that when a class is loaded into memory, `+load` of this class and `+load` methods of all its categories are supposed to be called before we can something with this class (like create an instance and call `didFinishLaunching...`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## TL,DR: It's xctest's fault, not objc's.

This is because of how the `xctest` executable (the one that actually runs the unit tests, located at `$XCODE_DIR/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/xctest` loads its bundle.

Pre-Xcode 7, it loaded **all** referenced test bundles before running any tests. This can be seen (for those that care), by disassembling the binary for Xcode 6.4, the relevant section can be seen for the symbol `-[XCTestTool runTestFromBundle:]`.

In the Xcode 7 version of `xctest`, you can see that it delays loading of testing bundles until the actual test is run by `XCTestSuite`, in the actual `XCTest` framework, which can be seen in the symbol `__XCTestMain`, which is only invoked AFTER the test's host application is set-up.

Because the order of these being invoked internally changed, the way that your test's `+load` methods are invoked is different. There were no changes made to the objective-c-runtime's internals.

If you want to fix this in your application, you can do a few things. First, you could manually load your bundle using `+[NSBundle bundleWithPath:]`, and invoking `-load` on that.

You could also link your test target back to your test host application (I hope you're using a separate test host than your main application!), which would make it be automatically loaded when xctest loads the host application.

I would not consider it a bug, it's just an implementation detail of XCTest.

Source: Just spend the last 3 days disassembling `xctest` for a completely unrelated reason.

Comment: Thank you very much! To be honest, I didn't expect to get such a quick and accurate answer for such question. I'm in luck :) Also, thank you for suggested workarounds.

Comment: Interesting. Would that explain `+load` methods being called twice like I'm seeing here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154729/xcode-7-xctestkiwi-load-category-methods-called-twice

Comment: I've got another question to you if you don't mind. You said that it is a good practice to use a separate host for unit tests. I tried to google materials about iOS unit testing best practices, but, unfortunately, couldn't find anything on the topic. Do you have links to any materials where I could read about best ways of implementing it? I tried to simply duplicate the main target, but it seems that this way I'll have to manually keep targets in sync. I thought that there must be some better way.

Comment: Another reason I want to read materials on the topic is because I want to read about advantages of this practice. Up until now using the main target as a unit test host worked fine for me, but probably I haven't come across cases where it is inconvenient (yet).

Comment: Your answer has finally inspired me to ask another question about XCTests: [Why should I use a separate test host for running XCTests and how should I do that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515825/why-should-i-use-a-separate-test-host-for-running-xctests-and-how-should-i-do-th). I would be glad if you could have a look.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 7 has *two* different load orders in the iOS template project.

**Unit Test Case.**  For Unit Test, the test bundle is *injected into* the running simulation after the application has launched through to the main screen.  The default Unit Test execution sequence is like the following:

```
Application: AppDelegate initialize()
Application: AppDelegate init()
Application: AppDelegate application(…didFinishLaunchingWithOptions…)
Application: ViewController viewDidLoad()
Application: ViewController viewWillAppear()
Application: AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive(…)
Application: ViewController viewDidAppear()
Unit Test: setup()
Unit Test: testExample()
```

**UI Test Case.**  For UI Test, a *separate second process* `XCTRunner` is set up which exercises the application under test. An argument can be passed from the test `setUp()` ...

```
class Launch_UITests: XCTestCase {

  override func setUp() {
    // … other code …
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launchArguments = ["UI_TESTING_MODE"]
    app.launch()
    // … other code …
  }
```

... to be received be the `AppDelegate` ...

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(… didFinishLaunchingWithOptions… ) -> Bool {
    // … other code …
    let args = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments
    if args.contains("UI_TESTING_MODE") {
        print("FOUND: UI_TESTING_MODE")
    }
    // … other code …
```

The *injection into* vs the *separate process* can be observed by printing `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().processIdentifier` and `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().processName` in from both the test code and the application code.