# Xcode 7 - Detecting when a specific unit test suite is running from within an iOS app

Tags: xcode, ios9, xctest

Under Xcode 6 / iOS 8 SDK and earlier, I could check the BOOL value of

`[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.mycompany.AppUnitTests"] != nil`

from inside my app to see if a certain set of unit tests were in progress.  (Note that I am running my tests as application tests, not as logic tests.)  As of Xcode 7 / iOS 9 SDK that seems to no longer work - the bundle is always returned as nil.  I suspect that Xcode 7 has changed the way that apps load and run their unit tests but I can't put my finger on it.  Anyone know a way to detect this that works under Xcode 7 / iOS 9 SDK?

(BTW, I know I can check `[NSBundle bundleForClass:NSClassFromString(@"XCTest")]` to find out if any set of unit tests are in progress, but I have several test suites and need to be able to differentiate between them; hence checking by bundle ID.  Thanks.)

**UPDATE:**
This change in behavior seems to be due to the change in bundle loading order described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639263/changed-load-method-order-in-xcode-7/32643245#32643245).  And, as Apple describes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-123081), `+bundleWithIdentifier:` only retrieves a reference to bundles that have already been loaded - hence I could not get a reference to the bundle that way when it had not yet loaded.  I guess the question now becomes, how do I get the test bundle to load before the app starts?

Comment: I ran into same problem. However, the workaround that you suggest (using NSBundle bundeForClass) works for my tests. Thanks for that!